# Vue.js: Prevent div from bubbling up to parent

Tags: html, vue.js, leaflet, quasar

i have a problem with the @click.stop in my vue application. I also use quasar and leaflet.

So in my app you can click different objects on a leaflet map. If an object is selected a q-drawer pops open. In the drawer I can click a few buttons and input fields to do some other actions.

If I click on them everything is working as intended, but if I click on the empty space of the drawer the drawer gets closed. This is because the map behind the drawer reacts through event bubbling on the click.

If I add the `@click.stop`to the drawer the event does not bubble up to the map, but also does not reach any buttons I wanna click...

Any advice what to do?

Comment: You can temporary disable leaflet interaction this way: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/54925

Comment: Thank you @amiria703. I will try this, but what worked out for me so far is just putting the drawers in a different div than the leaflet map container div.